# Why am I getting this weird behavior when zoom out after zooming in?

Tags: canvas, konvajs, react-konva, konva

I have stage which can be dragged, zoomed in and out. But, after zooming in the scale of the stage is 1.25 and drags the stage all the way to the bottom and zoom out, there is a huge white space showing up at the bottom. That happens only if we click zoom in once and zoom out again. Could you please help me with this issue? I have made a small minimal demo here

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-pan-zoom-forked-gmk80u?file=/src/App.js

To reproduce the issue

Please click zoom in button (only once, if clicked twice it won't happen)
Drag the Stage(image) to the bottom until you can no longer drag
Click zoom out

There you go, the image gets shorten and gets white space.

Comment: Did you solve this - on your linked demo I cannot reproduce the issue in the way that you described?

Comment: Yep, I found a solution

Comment: Cool. Can you share it? Folks provide input and feedback on this site voluntarily - sharing our own solutions is as important as solving other peoples questions.

Comment: Ok, sure. I just needed to update the coordinates of the Stage (x and y) after the drag end in order to solve the issue.